# How to replace the Last "s" with "" in PHP

Tags: php, string, replace

I need to know how I can replace the last "s" from a string with ""

Let's say I have a string like **testers** and the output should be **tester**.
It should just replace the last "s" and not every "s" in a string
how can I do that in PHP?

Comment: What about words like *this*, would it be *thi*?

Comment: Yes exactly, this would be thi

Comment: I am curious to ask, why? Also, what is the expected output of the string `your's`? Would you want that to be converted as well?

Comment: The last s of a string, on *any* location in that string or only if it is at the *real* end of the string. So what about "Test string"? Should it become "Test tring"?

Comment: is your end goal to remove all S's or just the s from words that are plural?(never had the need to pluralize s before... haha)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
if (substr($str, -1) == 's')
{
    $str = substr($str, 0, -1);
}
```

Comment: Removes only the `s` if it is the last character.

Comment: orly? may be becaue streetparade needs in this "Hi, I need to know how I can replace the last "s" from a string with """ ? ;-)))

Comment: How can I remove the the last `s` in `"String with s not in last position"`?

Comment: You'd need to break down the string into words first to make this work.

Comment: @Felix: you can remove with any solution you want, but streetparade needs only in removing "s" when it's actually last char in the string.

Comment: @zerkms: Where does he states this?

Comment: your answer is useful because of elegant preg. sorry for -1 vote. changed back :-(

Comment: @zerkms: Thank you. Deleted my comment anyway as it is not really helping the discussion ;)

Answer (score 17):

**Update:** Ok it is also possible without regular expressions using [`strrpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) ans [`substr_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php):

```
$str = "A sentence with 'Testers' in it";
echo substr_replace($str,'', strrpos($str, 's'), 1);
// Ouputs: A sentence with 'Tester' in it
```

`strrpos` returns the index of the last occurrence of a string and `substr_replace` replaces a string starting from a certain position.

(Which is the same as [**Gordon**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534597/how-to-replace-the-last-s-with-in-php/2534614#2534614) proposed as I just noticed.)

---

All answers so far remove the last character of a word. However if you really want to replace the **last occurrence** of a character, you can use [`preg_replace`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with a [*negative lookahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$s = "A sentence with 'Testers' in it";
echo preg_replace("%s(?!.*s.*)%", "", $string );

// Ouputs: A sentence with 'Tester' in it
```

Comment: dude, all he need is to replace 1 char from the string

Comment: lol. +1 to both of you. What an awesome answer. @Felix, if I asked you how to add int's in C++, would you start with "Well, first you create a boolean `carry` variable to store the carry after the addition of each bit."? :P

Comment: @zerkms: At least it is exactly what he asks for.

Comment: @incrediman: No of course not ;) But in my opinion it is better to start with a "not optimal" solution that produces the desired results and go on from there as with a fast solution that does not work in all cases.

Comment: @Felix: Yeah - well it's an interesting regex anyways :)

Comment: if you decide to solve your problem with regex - you get 2nd issue (can't find the original) ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Your question is somewhat unclear whether you want to remove the `s` from the end of the string or the last occurence of `s` in the string. It's a difference. If you want the first, use the solution offered by zerkms.

This function removes **the last occurence** of `$char` from `$string`, regardless of it's position in the string or returns the whole string, when $char does not occur in the string.

```
function removeLastOccurenceOfChar($char, $string)
{
    if( ($pos = strrpos($string, $char)) !== FALSE) {
        return substr_replace($string, '', $pos, 1);
    }
    return $string;
}
echo removeLastOccurenceOfChar('s', "the world's greatest");
// gives "the world's greatet"
```

If your intention is to inflect, e.g singularize/pluralize words, then [have a look at this simple inflector class](http://www.zend.com//code/codex.php?ozid=1564&single=1) to know which route to take.

Comment: nice sample, that demonstrates nothing ;-) function doanything($char, $string) { return $string; } will work in the same manner but do this faster

Comment: ah, i missed that "s" from "greatest" disappeared. i need glasses. anyway - this doesn't replaces "s" from the string only if "s" is at the last position

Comment: @zerkms I still dont get what you mean. The function replaces exactly the last *occurence* of the $char, regardless of where it is in the string. The OP wasn't clear about whether he wanted to remove the 's' from the *end* or the *last occurence*, which is a difference.

Answer (score 5):

```
$result = rtrim($str, 's');
$result = str_pad($result, strlen($str) - 1, 's');
```

See [rtrim()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

Comment: Supreme overkill in comparison to zerkms' solution :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = preg_replace("/s$/i","",rtrim($str));
```

Answer (score 0):

The very simplest solution is using [`rtrim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

That is *exactly what that function is intended to be used for*:
Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string.

Nothing simpler than that, I am not sure why, and would not follow the suggestions in this thread going from regex to "if/else" blocks.

This is your code:

```
$string = "Testers";
$stripped = rtrim( $string, 's' );
```

The output will be:
`Tester`